# Magento remove block only works with cache disabled

Tags: magento

I have a static block that gets added to the footer reference on every page. My homepage is a CMS page and I've put code in the pages Layout Update XML to remove the block from that page.

This is how it's added to the footer for all pages:

In page.xml inside

```
<reference name="footer">
  <block type="cms/block" name="page_cta" before="-">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>page_cta</block_id></action>
  </block>
</reference>
```

Code in my homepages layout update xml to remove the block:

```
<reference name="footer">
  <remove name="page_cta" />
</reference>
```

The block shouldn't show on the homepage and should show on all other pages. This works fine but only if the cache is disabled. What seems to happen is the cache is enabled then I view the homepage and the block is removed but then it is also removed on every other page.

Can anyone shed some light on why this doesn't work if the cache is enabled?

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/block_cache_and_html_ouput have you given this a try?

Comment: It could be that when you're enabling your cache that it's pulling from a cached copy previously stored.  After enabling your cache be sure to Flush it.

Comment: @seanbreeden tried to flush the cache after enabling it but no difference. thanks though

Answer (score 2):

Disable the cache for specific block like as mentioned below:

```
<reference name="footer">
       <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_lifetime</key></action>
       <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_tags</key></action>
       <block type="cms/block" name="page_cta" before="-">
           <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>page_cta</block_id></action>
       </block>
   </reference>
```